# setLogLevel as 'silent' for JS firestore 2022

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying the following to disable firestore logging:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/firestore';
firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('silent');
```

The import statement fails, however. Does anyone know how to do this in 2022? All of the posts I see are old and do not work even if I copy the code down verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest SDK versions, most APIs are top-level functions. So [`setLogLevel`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#setloglevel) is no longer a method on the Firestore service, but instead its own function that you pass a `Firestore` object to.

```
import { setLogLevel } from "firebase/firestore";

setLogLevel('silent');
```

Also see snippets in the Firebase documentation on [using Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9) and the  [upgrade guide for the modular SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had also tried that option first but it still appeared that there were error messages coming up, like in [this example](https://ibb.co/sHjy2WG). Is there any way to turn these messages off?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to suppress those error messages from the SDK, as they are system wide.